# Is it possible reduce the frequency angular.dart re-eval ng-repeat expression?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have the follow angular expression in my page and the associated dart function.

```dart
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="name in ctrl.getNames()">{{name}}</li>
</ul>
```

.

```dart
List<String> getNames() {
  print('ng-repeat triggered');
  return ['john', 'smith', 'david'];
}
```

The problem is by clicking anywhere on the page, or re-sizing the browser window, I would see 'ng-repeat triggered' being printed to my dartium console.

My question is what triggers angular to re-evaluate the expression, the above made it seems like any action on the page will trigger the re-evaluation.

Second, is there a way to reduce the frequeny or control when the angular expression will be evaluated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how Angular does change detection. I haven't seen anything about how to influence it.

A new change detection algorithm is on the way [AngularDart change detection](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10W46qDNO8Dl0Uye3QX0oUDPYAwaPl0qNy73TVLjd1WI/mobilebasic#heading=h.xgjl2srtytjt) (I haven't read it myself yet)

Comment: "The above algorithm is already implemented in AngularDart: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/pull/434."  What isn't done (according to that draft) is back-port it to Angular-JS.

Comment: Is this already released? Can you please remove two redundant chars at the end of the link

Comment: Yes, it is already released, because the pull request is closed.  I can't seem to edit a previous comment, sorry.